# Cannot index to elasticsearch from a web application

Tags: java, tomcat, elasticsearch

I have a web application running on tomcat that reads the log file and index them to elasticsearch.I use elasticsearch-6.1.1.I have add the elasticsearch-6.1.2 jar.But when i try to index to elasticsearch i get an error saying **Falied to load resource:internal server error(500).** What will be the problem.Any help would be great.Thanks in advance.

The code snippet for indexing is:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < length ; i++ )
            {
            outobj.println("inside loop");
            LinkedHashMap<String,Object> mapobj = (LinkedHashMap<String,Object>) list.get(i);

            IndexRequest indexRequest =new IndexRequest("logfilecontents","logs");//this line throws the error

            indexRequest.source(mapobj);

            IndexResponse indexResponse = client.index(indexRequest);
            }
```

Comment: Does elasticsearch process is running?

Comment: thanks for the response @Lax.i figured out the problem.it happened because i missed to add joda-time jar to the library.